# Subscript out of range error (Error 9): .FormatConditions

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

My code sometimes throws up an `Error 9, Subscript out of range` error. Amongst many other things, my code takes a load of cells and removes existing conditional formatting to them and then re-applies it adding in `i` number of conditions dependent on the number of items that have just been added to a range.

```
Function FormatLevelX()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim sLevelRangeName As String
For j = 1 To Sheets("LEVEL").Range("MajorLevels").Columns.Count 'repeat this for each of the major levels
    sLevelRangeName = "Level" & Sheets("LEVEL").Range("MajorLevels").Cells(1, j)
    For k = 1 To Sheets("LEVEL").Range(sLevelRangeName).Columns.Count 'repeat this for each column per major level
        For r = 2 To 5 'repeat this for each of the 4 cells (each on a different row) in the column that need conditional formatting
            With Sheets("LEVEL").Range(sLevelRangeName).Cells(r, k)
                    .FormatConditions.Delete
                    .Validation.Delete
                For i = 1 To Sheets("Level").Range("MajorLevels").Columns.Count 'make one rule per major level
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=MATCH(" & ColLett(Range(sLevelRangeName).Cells(2, k).Column) & "2,MajorLevels,0)=" & i
                        Select Case (i)
                        Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
                            .FormatConditions(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 45 + i
                            .FormatConditions(i).Font.Color = vbWhite
                            .FormatConditions(i).NumberFormat = "@"
                        Case 6
                            .FormatConditions(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 23
                            .FormatConditions(i).Font.Color = vbWhite
                            .FormatConditions(i).NumberFormat = "@"
                        Case 7, 8, 9
                            .FormatConditions(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 45 + i + 1
                            .FormatConditions(i).Font.Color = vbWhite
                            .FormatConditions(i).NumberFormat = "@"
                        Case Else
                            .FormatConditions(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 9 + i - 10
                            .FormatConditions(i).Font.Color = vbWhite
                            .FormatConditions(i).NumberFormat = "@"
                        End Select
                Next i
            End With
        Next r
    Next k
Next j

End Function
```

At the moment it is causing the error when i=12 and the error occurs under `Case Else, .FormatConditions(i).Font.Color = vbWhite.` It appears a little random as to when it happens, but frequently occurs on the `.Font.Color = vbWhite`. If I simply REM this out then it sometimes goes away (clearly not the solution!). Though will then appear on one of the other lines with format conditions being added.

Any help hugely appreciated.

Comment: + 1 For covering every detail while explaining your problem :) BTW I am kind of confused with the error message and the line you are pointing to and the reason why you think this might be happening. Subscript out of range error happens when Excel is not able to find a particular object. For example `FormatConditions(12)` but not because of `vbWhite`

Comment: I would expect more of a `'Run-time error '1004:'Application-defined or object-defined error` error on that line...

Comment: A shot in the dark. Can you try something for me? Change `.Font.Color = vbWhite` to `.Font.ColorIndex = 2`?

Comment: Yeah - it has never done that - always the Error 9. I have a load of other functions that format various ranges using very similar ways and they tend to kick out this error when the ranges get a little large (like over 9 items). I have deleted all the conditions initially before entering them, so can't for the life of me see what is going wrong

Comment: Hmm - i am not sure why it is picking on VBWhite, as it has just set the '.FormatConditions(12).interior.colorindex' on the previous line, so presumably has already found 'formatconditions(12)'

Comment: `so presumably has already found 'formatconditions(12)'` No, not necessarily true. It entered `Case Else` because the value of `i` is `12`. This leads me to another thought. Add `DoEvents` after `.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression,...` and try it as well.

Comment: So try both the things that I suggested above.. `1` .colorindex `2` doevents

Comment: ok,thanks, will do. It is running away now - i am awaiting for the error to kick it out of the code. Though i would have thought that when it entered case Else, that it would have run the line .FormatConditions(12).interior.colorindex' before the vbWbite line and at that point had to have found the formatconditions(12) to add that condition - if it was not found then it should have created the error on that line. That was my logic around it anyway, though i am pretty new to this. Still awaiting for the error to come up...

Comment: There is a contradiction between the error message and the line of error like I mentioned in my first comment. For example If it didn't find `FormatConditions(12)` then why did it run the prev line `.FormatConditions(i).Interior.ColorIndex` And if it did find then why that error message. Hence I am not very sure of a definitive answer.

Comment: Its churning away - changing the offending line to `.font.colorindex = 2` did not help, so i am going to add in the DoEvents and see what that leads to

Comment: So if it was in fact an application defined error then what kind of thing could be causing it - probably impossible to answer, but just in case there is something obvious to look for in these circumstances.

Comment: Will come to that in a moment. What happened with `DoEvents`?

Comment: Also - what exactly is the DoEvents line doing and what is it applying to - i may go and start adding it in to my other functions which kicks out this error...

Comment: DoEvents - just put in, rerunning code now to see where it gets to

Comment: DoEvents will give excel enough time to add that format condition.

Comment: Neither worked - I changed/added both ideas and unfortunately the error appears on the same line. The DoEvents appeared to slow down the code considerably, which sounds like it was doing its job

Comment: One last thing then. May I see your file?

Comment: Its odd, as when i remark out the `vbwhite` (or changed `.font.colourindex`) line then it completes the code and therefore sets the 12th format condition including the `interior.colourindex` and the `.numberformat`. No idea - may just remark out all of the vbwhite and fix that as a condition, though i am sure i have tried that before and it pushes the error code onto another format condition line

Comment: so `.font.colourindex` as I suggested works?

Comment: Thanks! - but it is quite large and complex in terms of there is loads of code there, but would appreciate the help - how do i go about sending it your way?

Comment: ah no - .font.colourindex made no difference

Comment: you can load it to www.wikisend.com and share the link here

Comment: You know what - i just Rem out all of the lines with vbwhite in and it has completed with no errors - i think it will be good for now working with that. Many thanks for all of your help, really appreciated.

Comment: Whatever rocks your boat :D

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the following change then breakpoint on newFC to determine it's contents:

```
Dim newFC As FormatCondition
set newFC = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlEqual, _
     Formula1:="=MATCH(" & ColLett(Range(sLevelRangeName).Cells(2, k).Column) & _
    "2,MajorLevels,0)=" & i)
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks. I havn't implemented your suggestion, but it is a good one to find out what is going wrong. Very oddly the problem is resolved when i remove the formatCondition being set as vbWhite. Problem just goes away. It crops up all over my code (have about 10,000 lines of code) and everywhere it crops up it is always where FormatCondition is set to vbWhite. I remove that line of code and all is good. Who knows why - hope this "discovery" will help others. Thanks for all your sugestions