# Setting Excel FormatConditions Font Color Run-time Error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, conditional-formatting

I am receiving a run-time error '1004' on the line `.Font.color = vbRed` when setting conditional formats.  The `Sub` works great on Excel 2011 for Mac, but fails on Windows.

I've tried rearranging the code, using `RGB(255,0,0)`, setting `.ColorIndex`, as well as recording a macro and using that code.  All failed in windows.

I'm trying to set the font color to red if the cell begins with "Med".  The sub is called from here:

```
  Public Const BASE As String = "$D$14"
```

---

```
  Dim cols As Long
  Dim rows As Long
  Dim applyToRange As Range
  Dim condition As String

 ' rows and cols variables set here...

  Set applyToRange = Range(BASE, Range(BASE).Offset(rows - 1, cols - 1))

  ' Med
  condition = "Med"
  applyTextStringConditionals applyToRange, condition, xlBeginsWith, 0, False
```

What am I missing?

```
Private Sub applyTextStringConditionals(ByVal applyToRange As Range, ByVal matchString As String, _
        ByVal operator As Long, ByVal color As Long, ByVal stopIfTrue As Boolean)

    applyToRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:=matchString, TextOperator:=operator
    applyToRange.FormatConditions(applyToRange.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    If color = 0 Then
        With applyToRange.FormatConditions(1)
              .Font.color = vbRed '<--- Error 1004 here
              '.TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    Else
        applyToRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.color = color
    End If
    applyToRange.FormatConditions(1).stopIfTrue = stopIfTrue
End Sub
```

---

**UPDATE:**

This works, *only* if it's the first conditional format created:

```
 Set applyToRange = Range(BASE, Range(BASE).Offset(rows - 12, cols - 1))
 ' Med
 condition = "Med"
 Stop
 applyToRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:=condition, TextOperator:=xlBeginsWith
 applyToRange.FormatConditions(applyToRange.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
 applyToRange.FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = vbRed '-16776961
 applyToRange.FormatConditions(1).stopIfTrue = True
```

But this does not:

```
Private Sub applyTextStringConditionals(ByVal l_applyToRange As Range, ByVal matchString As String, _
                    ByVal l_Operator As Long, ByVal setColor As Long, ByVal l_stopIfTrue As Boolean)

    l_applyToRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:=matchString, TextOperator:=l_Operator
    l_applyToRange.FormatConditions(l_applyToRange.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    If setColor = 0 Then
        l_applyToRange.FormatConditions.Item(1).Font.Color = vbRed
    Else
        l_applyToRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = setColor
    End If
    l_applyToRange.FormatConditions(1).stopIfTrue = True
end sub
```

Comment: Your code works for me, have you checked you are passing all the needed parameters to `Sub applyTextStringConditionals` ?

Comment: Yes, the parameters are all being passed.  I'm using the sub to set about 15 conditions _before_ the failure call above, most of which are `.Interior.color` not `.Font.color`, and all those are applied without error.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error with the current code, and test I've conducted

Comment: I appreciate you taking a look - using a govt computer with Excel 2010 (I think), maybe there's a bug in setting `.Font.color` in this manner. Works great on Excel Mac 2011 and Excel Mac 2016.

Comment: To clarify my above comment: the 15 conditions set before the failure are _all_ of the `.Interior.color` variety; it fails on the first attempt to set `.Font.color`.

Comment: try changing your variable name `color` to something else than Excel's saved word `color` - it;s not recomended using the same names Excel uses, try using `MyColor` instead.

Comment: Correction: Excel 2007 with SP2. Also, changed all variable names to not match any saved words. No luck yet.

Comment: I did find these threads that seem to indicate a bug in excel 2007's implementation of VBA... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685822/run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range-with-conditional-format-code

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132561/subscript-out-of-range-error-error-9-formatconditions

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715989/conditional-formatting-of-overlapping-ranges-in-excel-2007-vba-bug